# How do I use AdaptiveTriggers to change the font size of a StackPanel?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, stackpanel, adaptive-trigger

In the XAML code below, I have multiple VisualStates. Each VisualState has an AdaptiveTrigger that searches for a minimum window width. My goal is to have the StackPanel's FontSize increase as the window size increases.

I've tried this by setting the `VisualState.Setter` as follows: `Target="stackPanel.FontSize" Value="20"/>` or `Value="30"` or `Value="40"`, depending on the size of the window. This would occur whenever the `AdaptiveTrigger.MinWindowWidth` value is met. But this does not work as I had hoped.

Here is my sample code:

```xml
<Grid>
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualState x:Name="LargeScreen">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <!--Increase FontSize to 40 when window width is >=1000 effective pixels.-->
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="1000"/>
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="stackPanel.FontSize" Value="40"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>

            <VisualState x:Name="MediumScreen">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <!--Increase FontSize to 30 when window width >=720 effective pixels.-->
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="720"/>
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="stackPanel.FontSize" Value="30"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>

            <VisualState x:Name="SmallScreen">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <!--Increase FontSize to 20 when window width >=200 effective pixels.-->
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="200"/>
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="stackPanel.FontSize" Value="20"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

    <StackPanel x:Name="stackPanel" Orientation="Vertical" >
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="10" />
            </Style>
        </StackPanel.Resources>
        <TextBlock Text="Sample text line 1." />
        <TextBlock Text="Sample text line 2." />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Interestingly, and as an entirely separate note, if you change the setter from this this:

```xml
<VisualState.Setters>
    <Setter Target="stackPanel.FontSize" Value="20"/>
</VisualState.Setters>
```

To this:

```xml
<VisualState.Setters>
    <Setter Target="stackPanel.Orientation" Value="Horizontal"/>
</VisualState.Setters>
```

Then the StackPanel's orientation is changed to Horizontal whenever the `AdaptiveTrigger.MinWindowWidth` value is met. I'm not sure what is different between `stackPanel.Orientation` and `stackPanel.FontSize`, but one clearly works in this context, and the other does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no property called `FontSize` for the [StackPanel Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.stackpanel?view=winrt-22621) and the StackPanel Class does contain an `Orientation` property. That's why `stackPanel.Orientation` works but `stackPanel.FontSize` failed.

If you want to change the size of `TextBlock`, you need to call `TextBlock.FontSize`. For example:

```
  <VisualState x:Name="LargeScreen">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <!--Increase FontSize to 40 when window width is >=1000 effective pixels.-->
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="1000"/>
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="TextBlockOne.FontSize" Value="40"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>

 <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlockOne" Text="Sample text line 1." />
```

**Update:**

You could bind the FontSize property of other TextBlocks to the `TextBlockOne`. So when the FontSize property of the `TextBlockOne` changes, other TextBlocks change as well.

Like this:

```
   <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlockOne" Text="Sample text line 1." />
        <TextBlock  Text="Sample text line 2." FontSize="{Binding FontSize, ElementName=TextBlockOne,Mode=TwoWay}" />
        <TextBlock  Text="Sample text line 3." FontSize="{Binding FontSize, ElementName=TextBlockOne,Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Comment: Hey, thanks a ton. Using your example, I named each `TextBlock` and referenced them inside `<VisualState.Setters>`, like so: `<Setter Target="Block1.FontSize" Value="20"/>` and then: `<Setter Target="Block2.FontSize" Value="20"/>`. Although I wonder if there is a way to change the properties of more than one TextBlock without having to reference each one by name?

Comment: @Ramza You could bind the FontSize property of other TextBlocks to the `TextBlockOne`. So when the FontSize property of the `TextBlockOne` changes, other TextBlocks change as well. I've updated my answer with sample code, please check it.